# how to plot region-based color coding python

Tags: python, matplotlib, color-codes

how to plot the following in python? I have 1000 points in 2d. I need to color-code them based on their position in the 2d space as following
moving along x-axis increases the green color
moving along y-axis increases red color
moving along the y=x line, increases green and red equally

the blue color of all points are equal to each other and zero
The points are representing error between two ideas (models). So each point is has two values point = [p_x, p_y].
p_x and p_y range between 0 to 1 like the following:

```
points = np.random.rand(1000, 2)
so each point p = [p_x, p_y]
```

as an example, the following code makes a scatter plot that the color of points depends on the y location.

```
# Generate data...
x = np.random.random(10)
y = np.random.random(10)

# Plot...
plt.scatter(x, y, c=y, s=100)

plt.show()
```

How I can make the color of each point to be based on 2d location in the space, to be depend on both `p_x` and `p_y` so that points with higher `p_x` are greener and points with higher `p_y` are reder

[image]

Comment: Do you mind to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)? I mean original `df` and the condition for colors.

Comment: points can be any 2d array. I updated the problem with an example as requested

Comment: Now it will be great to add the conditions for the color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just calculate an RGB value based on your `points` array and use `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter` with the `color` parameter:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
points = np.random.rand(1000, 2)*180

# calculate Red, Green, Blue channels from 0 to 1 based on min/max of points:
R = (points[:,0] - points[:,0].min())/(points[:,0].max()-points[:,0].min())
G = (points[:,1] - points[:,1].min())/(points[:,1].max()-points[:,1].min())
B=np.zeros(R.shape)

# stack those RGB channels into a N x 3 array:
clrs=np.column_stack((R,G,B)) 

plt.scatter(points[:,0],points[:,1],color=clrs)
plt.show()
```

Results in

[image: point color by position]

EDIT: oops, look like I flipped the directions of the R and G variation you wanted, but this should be enough to get you going.